# ActiveAndroid Nested Model

Tags: android, activeandroid, libs

I am using ActiveAndroid and have two models:

```
@Table(name = "Topics")
public class Topic extends Model {
@Column(name = "Name") String name;

@SerializedName("id")
@Column(index = true,
        unique = true,
        onUniqueConflict = Column.ConflictAction.REPLACE) public long topic_id;
@Column(name = "Counts",
        onUpdate = Column.ForeignKeyAction.CASCADE,
        onDelete = Column.ForeignKeyAction.CASCADE) Counts counts;
}
```

and

```
@Table(name = "Counts")
public class Counts extends Model {
@Column(name = "Users") int users;
}
```

Constructors have been excluded for brevity. 
Now, when i save Topic, I expect the Counts to be saved. But it does not.
I am using gson to create the models from json. Any reason why counts are not being loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to call `count.save()` then you can call `topic.save()`. ActiveAndroid needs the **id** to get the reference and that happen when you save it.